# Генерация отчета в JasperReports

Tags: eclipse, jasperreports

Пытаюсь сгенерить отчет в Eclipse с использованием шаблона JasperReports. Суть в чем:
Есть база  на 50 000 записей. Нужно сделать по отчёту на каждую запись. Т.е. параметры(поля) одни и те же, изменяется лишь значение. 
При попытке сделать что-либо похожее, jasper просто выводит все записи по порядку, и если они вылезают за пределы секции detail то переходят на новую страницу.
Может есть вариант как можно генерировать каждый отчет по отдельности?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

расширить detail на всю страницу

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]